# jquery ui datatables css problems

Tags: jquery, css, datatable

so i've got no idea what is going on.

Installed datatables jquery plugin, it's working.

Downloaded a css code from [theme creator](http://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/theme-creator).

css is working but not fully, some things display some others don't. I've disabled all the other css from the web, so the only one now is the one of the datatables.

Still the same problem, here is the css code:

```
/*
 * Table styles
 */
table.dataTable {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  /*
   * Header and footer styles
   */
  /*
   * Body styles
   */ }
  table.dataTable thead th,
  table.dataTable tfoot th {
    font-weight: bold; }
  table.dataTable thead th,
  table.dataTable thead td {
    padding: 10px 18px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #111111; }
    table.dataTable thead th:active,
    table.dataTable thead td:active {
      outline: none; }
  table.dataTable tfoot th,
  table.dataTable tfoot td {
    padding: 10px 18px 6px 18px;
    border-top: 1px solid #111111; }
  table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc,
  table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc,
  table.dataTable thead .sorting {
    cursor: pointer;
    *cursor: hand; }
  table.dataTable thead .sorting {
    background: url("../images/datatables/sort_both.png") no-repeat center right; }
  table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc {
    background: url("../images/datatables/sort_asc.png") no-repeat center right; }
  table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc {
    background: url("../images/datatables/sort_desc.png") no-repeat center right; }
  table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled {
    background: url("../images/datatables/sort_asc_disabled.png") no-repeat center right; }
  table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled {
    background: url("../images/datatables/sort_desc_disabled.png") no-repeat center right; }
  table.dataTable tbody tr {
    background-color: white; }
    table.dataTable tbody tr.selected {
      background-color: #336699; }
  table.dataTable tbody th,
  table.dataTable tbody td {
    padding: 8px 10px; }
  table.dataTable.row-border tbody th, table.dataTable.row-border tbody td, table.dataTable.display tbody th, table.dataTable.display tbody td {
    border-top: 1px solid #dddddd; }
  table.dataTable.row-border tbody tr:first-child th,
  table.dataTable.row-border tbody tr:first-child td, table.dataTable.display tbody tr:first-child th,
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr:first-child td {
    border-top: none; }
  table.dataTable.cell-border tbody th, table.dataTable.cell-border tbody td {
    border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #dddddd; }
  table.dataTable.cell-border tbody tr th:first-child,
  table.dataTable.cell-border tbody tr td:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid #dddddd; }
  table.dataTable.cell-border tbody tr:first-child th,
  table.dataTable.cell-border tbody tr:first-child td {
    border-top: none; }
  table.dataTable.stripe tbody tr.odd, table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd {
    background-color: #f9f9f9; }
    table.dataTable.stripe tbody tr.odd.selected, table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd.selected {
      background-color: #316395; }
  table.dataTable.hover tbody tr:hover,
  table.dataTable.hover tbody tr.odd:hover,
  table.dataTable.hover tbody tr.even:hover, table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover,
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd:hover,
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even:hover {
    background-color: whitesmoke; }
    table.dataTable.hover tbody tr:hover.selected,
    table.dataTable.hover tbody tr.odd:hover.selected,
    table.dataTable.hover tbody tr.even:hover.selected, table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover.selected,
    table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd:hover.selected,
    table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even:hover.selected {
      background-color: #316293; }
  table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr > .sorting_1,
  table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr > .sorting_2,
  table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr > .sorting_3, table.dataTable.display tbody tr > .sorting_1,
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr > .sorting_2,
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr > .sorting_3 {
    background-color: #f9f9f9; }
  table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr.selected > .sorting_1,
  table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr.selected > .sorting_2,
  table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr.selected > .sorting_3, table.dataTable.display tbody tr.selected > .sorting_1,
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.selected > .sorting_2,
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.selected > .sorting_3 {
    background-color: #316395; }
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd > .sorting_1, table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd > .sorting_1 {
    background-color: #f1f1f1; }
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd > .sorting_2, table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd > .sorting_2 {
    background-color: #f3f3f3; }
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd > .sorting_3, table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd > .sorting_3 {
    background-color: whitesmoke; }
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd.selected > .sorting_1, table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd.selected > .sorting_1 {
    background-color: #306090; }
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd.selected > .sorting_2, table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd.selected > .sorting_2 {
    background-color: #306191; }
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd.selected > .sorting_3, table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd.selected > .sorting_3 {
    background-color: #316293; }
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even > .sorting_1, table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even > .sorting_1 {
    background-color: #f9f9f9; }
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even > .sorting_2, table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even > .sorting_2 {
    background-color: #fbfbfb; }
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even > .sorting_3, table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even > .sorting_3 {
    background-color: #fdfdfd; }
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even.selected > .sorting_1, table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even.selected > .sorting_1 {
    background-color: #316395; }
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even.selected > .sorting_2, table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even.selected > .sorting_2 {
    background-color: #326497; }
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even.selected > .sorting_3, table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even.selected > .sorting_3 {
    background-color: #326598; }
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover > .sorting_1,
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd:hover > .sorting_1,
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even:hover > .sorting_1, table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover > .sorting_1,
  table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr.odd:hover > .sorting_1,
  table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr.even:hover > .sorting_1 {
    background-color: #eaeaea; }
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover > .sorting_2,
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd:hover > .sorting_2,
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even:hover > .sorting_2, table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover > .sorting_2,
  table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr.odd:hover > .sorting_2,
  table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr.even:hover > .sorting_2 {
    background-color: #ebebeb; }
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover > .sorting_3,
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd:hover > .sorting_3,
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even:hover > .sorting_3, table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover > .sorting_3,
  table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr.odd:hover > .sorting_3,
  table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr.even:hover > .sorting_3 {
    background-color: #eeeeee; }
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover.selected > .sorting_1,
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd:hover.selected > .sorting_1,
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even:hover.selected > .sorting_1, table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover.selected > .sorting_1,
  table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr.odd:hover.selected > .sorting_1,
  table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr.even:hover.selected > .sorting_1 {
    background-color: #2e5d8c; }
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover.selected > .sorting_2,
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd:hover.selected > .sorting_2,
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even:hover.selected > .sorting_2, table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover.selected > .sorting_2,
  table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr.odd:hover.selected > .sorting_2,
  table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr.even:hover.selected > .sorting_2 {
    background-color: #2f5e8d; }
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover.selected > .sorting_3,
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd:hover.selected > .sorting_3,
  table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even:hover.selected > .sorting_3, table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover.selected > .sorting_3,
  table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr.odd:hover.selected > .sorting_3,
  table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr.even:hover.selected > .sorting_3 {
    background-color: #2f5f8f; }
  table.dataTable.no-footer {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #111111; }
  table.dataTable.nowrap th, table.dataTable.nowrap td {
    white-space: nowrap; }
  table.dataTable.compact thead th,
  table.dataTable.compact thead td {
    padding: 5px 9px; }
  table.dataTable.compact tfoot th,
  table.dataTable.compact tfoot td {
    padding: 5px 9px 3px 9px; }
  table.dataTable.compact tbody th,
  table.dataTable.compact tbody td {
    padding: 4px 5px; }
  table.dataTable th.dt-left,
  table.dataTable td.dt-left {
    text-align: left; }
  table.dataTable th.dt-center,
  table.dataTable td.dt-center,
  table.dataTable td.dataTables_empty {
    text-align: center; }
  table.dataTable th.dt-right,
  table.dataTable td.dt-right {
    text-align: right; }
  table.dataTable th.dt-justify,
  table.dataTable td.dt-justify {
    text-align: justify; }
  table.dataTable th.dt-nowrap,
  table.dataTable td.dt-nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap; }
  table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-left,
  table.dataTable thead td.dt-head-left,
  table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-left,
  table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-left {
    text-align: left; }
  table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-center,
  table.dataTable thead td.dt-head-center,
  table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-center,
  table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-center {
    text-align: center; }
  table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-right,
  table.dataTable thead td.dt-head-right,
  table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-right,
  table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-right {
    text-align: right; }
  table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-justify,
  table.dataTable thead td.dt-head-justify,
  table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-justify,
  table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-justify {
    text-align: justify; }
  table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-nowrap,
  table.dataTable thead td.dt-head-nowrap,
  table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-nowrap,
  table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap; }
  table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-left,
  table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-left {
    text-align: left; }
  table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-center,
  table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-center {
    text-align: center; }
  table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-right,
  table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-right {
    text-align: right; }
  table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-justify,
  table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-justify {
    text-align: justify; }
  table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-nowrap,
  table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap; }

table.dataTable,
table.dataTable th,
table.dataTable td {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box; }

/*
 * Control feature layout
 */
.dataTables_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  *zoom: 1;
  zoom: 1; }
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length {
    float: left; }
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter {
    float: right;
    text-align: right; }
    .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter input {
      margin-left: 0.5em; }
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 0.755em; }
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 0.25em; }
    .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      display: inline-block;
      min-width: 1.5em;
      padding: 0.5em 1em;
      margin-left: 2px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none !important;
      cursor: pointer;
      *cursor: hand;
      color: #333333 !important;
      border: 1px solid transparent; }
      .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current:hover {
        color: #333333 !important;
        border: 1px solid #2a547e;
        background-color: #85add6;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #85add6), color-stop(100%, #336699));
        /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #85add6 0%, #336699 100%);
        /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #85add6 0%, #336699 100%);
        /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #85add6 0%, #336699 100%);
        /* IE10+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #85add6 0%, #336699 100%);
        /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #85add6 0%, #336699 100%);
        /* W3C */ }
      .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled:hover, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled:active {
        cursor: default;
        color: #666 !important;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        background: transparent;
        box-shadow: none; }
      .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button:hover {
        color: white !important;
        border: 1px solid #001aad;
        background-color: #3d5aff;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #3d5aff), color-stop(100%, #001aad));
        /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3d5aff 0%, #001aad 100%);
        /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3d5aff 0%, #001aad 100%);
        /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3d5aff 0%, #001aad 100%);
        /* IE10+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3d5aff 0%, #001aad 100%);
        /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3d5aff 0%, #001aad 100%);
        /* W3C */ }
      .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button:active {
        outline: none;
        background-color: #0022e0;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #0022e0), color-stop(100%, #0018a3));
        /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0022e0 0%, #0018a3 100%);
        /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0022e0 0%, #0018a3 100%);
        /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0022e0 0%, #0018a3 100%);
        /* IE10+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0022e0 0%, #0018a3 100%);
        /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0022e0 0%, #0018a3 100%);
        /* W3C */
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #111; }
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_processing {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: -50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background-color: white;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)), color-stop(75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    /* W3C */ }
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length,
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter,
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info,
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_processing,
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate {
    color: #333333; }
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll {
    clear: both; }
    .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody {
      *margin-top: -1px;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; }
      .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody th > div.dataTables_sizing,
      .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody td > div.dataTables_sizing {
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important; }
  .dataTables_wrapper.no-footer .dataTables_scrollBody {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #111111; }
  .dataTables_wrapper.no-footer div.dataTables_scrollHead table,
  .dataTables_wrapper.no-footer div.dataTables_scrollBody table {
    border-bottom: none; }
  .dataTables_wrapper:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    height: 0; }

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info,
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate {
    float: none;
    text-align: center; }
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate {
    margin-top: 0.5em; } }
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length,
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter {
    float: none;
    text-align: center; }
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter {
    margin-top: 0.5em; } }
```

[image: The errors i don't know what to do with]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include the bootstrap files?

Look at this link: 
[Datatables Bootstrap](http://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap)

Comment: Thanks a lot i didn't include the css boostrap and the js boostrap files :)